# How to handle cache metadata in a cacheable response?

Tags: 8, caching

I have a custom controller action that returns the HTML for a search result. The action is invoked via AJAX on the search page and the results are inserted into the page body.

The problem is that a dynamic page cache entry is created for this controller action and it's not "busted" when the query string changes, so old results are always returned:

```
  public function basicPeopleSearch(Request $request) {
    $search = $request->query->get('search');
    $build = [];
    if (!empty($search)) {
      // Get search results and add them to the render array.
      $results = \Drupal::getContainer()->get('pu_search.people_search')->basicSearch($search);

      foreach ($results as $result) {
        $build[] = [
          '#theme' => 'pu_search_person',
          '#person' => $result,
        ];
      }
    }

    // The results will differ based on the "search" query string parameter.
    $build['#cache'] = [
      'contexts' => [
        'url.query_args:search',
      ],
    ];

    $rendered = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot($build);
    return new CacheableResponse($rendered);
  }
```

I suspect this has something to do with how I'm actually returning the response or rendering the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the cacheable metadata from the render array to the response:

```
use Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheableMetadata;

  $rendered = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot($build);
  $response = new CacheableResponse($rendered);
  $response->addCacheableDependency(CacheableMetadata::createFromRenderArray($build));
  return $response;
```