# Error when get rest resource : The controller result claims to be providing relevant cache metadata

Tags: entities, caching, 8

I try to create a REST resource. I used [EntityResource](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21rest%21src%21Plugin%21rest%21resource%21EntityResource.php/class/EntityResource/8.4.x) as base. I would like to return my fields in html.
Here is a exemple of my code :

```
public function get($id) {
    if (!$this->currentUser->hasPermission('access content')) {
      throw new AccessDeniedHttpException();
    }

    $entity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->load($id);
    $entity_access = $entity->access('view', NULL, TRUE);
    if (!$entity_access->isAllowed()) {
      throw new AccessDeniedHttpException($entity_access->getReason() ? : $this->generateFallbackAccessDeniedMessage($entity, 'view'));
    }

    $result = array();
    $other_entity_dependency = array();
    if ($entity instanceof FieldableEntityInterface) {
      $fields = array();
      $contentType = $entity->bundle();
      if (isset($contentType) && !empty($contentType)) {
        foreach (\Drupal::entityManager()->getFieldDefinitions('node', $contentType) as $field_name => $field_definition) {
          if (!empty($field_definition->getTargetBundle())) {
            $fields[] = $field_name;
          }
        }
      }
      foreach ($fields as $field_name) {
        $field = $entity->$field_name;
        $field_access = $field->access('view', NULL, TRUE);
        if ($field_access->isAllowed()) {
           $value = \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($field->view())
           $result[$field_name]['value'] = $value;
            $result[$field_name]['label'] = $field->getFieldDefinition()->getLabel();

        }
      }
    }


    $response = new ResourceResponse($result, Response::HTTP_OK);
    $response->addCacheableDependency($entity);
    $response->addCacheableDependency($entity_access);

      return $response;
  }
```

The problem is that when I use a render function, I have this error :

> The controller result claims to be providing relevant cache metadata,
>   but leaked metadata was detected. Please ensure you are not rendering
>   content too early. Returned object class:
>   Drupal\rest\ResourceResponse.

I haven't this issue when I use `$field->value` instead of `\Drupal::service('renderer')->render($field->view())`, but I would like to have the html render of fields, for file or image too (these types of fields are empty when I use `$field->value`).

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Don't render arrays get rendered anyway? Can't you just use `$value = $field->view()` and be done with it?

Comment: When use only `$value = $field->view()` I get this error : _Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\\Component\\Serializer\\Exception\\UnexpectedValueException: "Could not normalize object of type Drupal\\Core\\Url, no supporting normalizer found."_

Comment: Actually I guess that makes sense, there's no context available - how would it know what theme to use, for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that `render()` produces metadata which leaks to the outside of the controller. You can try `renderPlain()` if you don't care about the metadata or see this question how to provide your own render context to catch the metadata and add it to the response:

[How to get cache metadata from nested render array when returning response?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/245715/how-to-get-cache-metadata-from-nested-render-array-when-returning-response)

Comment: Thanks, I use the exemple that you give and now all metadata are catched. : the error is gone away.