# $node->save() fails when run in post_update

Tags: 9

I have a simple hook_post_update function which fails with the following error:

> [notice] Update started: ssc_custom_post_update_9001
>
> > [error]  LogicException: Render context is empty, because render() was called outside of a renderRoot() or renderPlain() call. Use
> > renderPlain()/renderRoot() or #lazy_builder/#pre_render instead. in
> > Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender() (line 244 of
> > E:\www\myssc\html\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer.php).
> > [error]  Render context is empty, because render() was called outside of a renderRoot() or renderPlain() call. Use
> > renderPlain()/renderRoot() or #lazy_builder/#pre_render instead.
> > [error]  Update failed: ssc_custom_post_update_9001
>
> In ProcessBase.php line 171:
>
> Unable to decode output into JSON: Syntax error
>
> [ERROR] [node] [2022-03-12T04:58:35] LogicException: Render context
> is empty, because render() was called    outside of a renderRoot() or
> renderPlain() call. Use renderPlain()/renderRoot() or
> #lazy_builder/#pre_re   nder instead. in Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender() (line 244 of
> E:\www\myssc\html\core\lib\Drupal\C   ore\Render\Renderer.php). | uid:
> 0 | request-uri: http://default/ | refer:  | ip:  127.0.0.1 | link:
> {
> "0": {
> "ssc_custom": {
> "9001": {
> "#abort": {
> "success": false,
> "query": "Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException:
> Ren   der context is empty, because render() was called outside of a
> renderRoot() or renderPlain() call. Use re   nderPlain()/renderRoot()
> or #lazy_builder/#pre_render instead. in Drupal\Core\Ent
> ity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->save() (line 810 of E:\www\myssc\html\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage.php)."
> }
> }
> },
> "#abort": [
> "ssc_custom_post_update_9001"
> ]
> },
> "drush_batch_process_finished": true   }

I have stripped the code down to the bare minimum:

```
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface;
use Drupal\node\NodeInterface;

function ssc_custom_post_update_9001(&$sandbox) {
  /** @var \Drupal\node\NodeStorageInterface $node_storage */
  $node_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node');

  // How many entities to processed per batch.
  $limit = 5;

  $node_ids = $node_storage->getQuery()
    ->accessCheck(FALSE)
    ->condition('type', 'article')
    ->range(0, $limit)
    ->execute();
  // Load entities.
  $nodes = $node_storage->loadMultiple($node_ids);

  /** @var \Drupal\node\NodeInterface $node */
  foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $node->setNewRevision();
    $node->save();
  }

  $sandbox['#finished'] = 1;

}
```

If I run the same code directly (not from drush updb) it runs fine. Running from the admin menu "Run updates"; it also fails (so it is not a drush issue).

Commenting out the $node->save() and the error does not occur.

Comment: Does this happen if you load and save a different content type?

Comment: This is not how batch works. Content updates should happen in `hook_deploy_N` running after configuration import when executing `drush deploy`.

Comment: If an error occurs in a Drupal function used in many different places you have to check the call stack from where it is called. This might point to a module which hooks into the node save process.

Comment: Hmm, oddly i am no longer getting notifications from Drupal Answers.. @sonfd, yes, any content type. leymannx, not sure what hook_deploy is, will take a look; but hook_post_update states it is specifically for tasks like this when you need to update site content and examples even show using batch and node save: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_post_update_NAME/9.0.x

Comment: @4uk4, yes, that was my next plan.. debug in core to see where this fails and see if i can tell which module is causing this. I have removed all my custom code (which did have node save) and it wasnt the issue. Odd there isn't a way to run an update that  is able to bypass this issue as it does seem silly to have fix a dozen (yes, likely not that many) contrib modules to do a simple content update. Alternatively i can give my clients a button to push after the site is upgraded; but certainly a regression from D7 that i can't have my deploy script do the update.

Comment: @leymannz, there is no such thing as hook_deploy - possibly something added by a contrib module? Deploy perhaps?

Comment: It’s a drush hook @liquidcms

Answer (score 2):

You can reproduce the error with Drush:

```
# drush php

>>> $build = ['#markup' => 'TEST'];
=> [
     "#markup" => "TEST",
   ]

>>> $rendered = \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($build);
LogicException with message 'Render context is empty, because render() was called outside of a renderRoot() or renderPlain() call. Use renderPlain()/renderRoot() or #lazy_builder/#pre_render instead.'

>>> $rendered = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderPlain($build);
=> Drupal\Core\Render\Markup {#4668
     markup: "TEST",
   }
```

So as the error message says modules which hook into the node save process should use renderPlain() instead. They shouldn't assume nodes are always saved within a render context of a themed Drupal page.

Code example for rendering a view in isolation:

```
$build = $view->buildRenderable();
$rendered = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderPlain($build);
```

Comment: Turns out it is my custom code causing the issue. I have code which runs on node save/presave which is trying to get values from a View and is using advancedRender() which i assume is causing this issue. Disappointing that my code works as it should when nodes are normally being saved but in post_update i am blocked from doing this. Easy enough to work around as these functions dont need to be run during this update - but odd I would need to do this hack.

Comment: If the render() function is not in your control, like here in a View, you can enclose the code in your own RenderContext and discard the bubbled up metadata. Drupal does this for example when rendering mails. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/245715/how-to-get-cache-metadata-from-nested-render-array-when-returning-response

Comment: thanks for the tip.. good to know. Although a lot of work to simply copy a field to a new field as a 1 time ting. For now i simply set a static var in the update script and then use that to ignore my save/presave functions as they don't need to be run when this update is being run.

Comment: OK, but this doesn't solve the problem with leaking metadata into an unknown render context. Running render() or code containing render() should only bubble up metadata if you can make sure the render context belongs to the rendered content. Most times this is the page render context when theming page elements.