# Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response is never cached

Tags: caching

My custom controller is returning data but it is never being cached.

My controller function:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

 $build = [
            '#theme' => 'search_form_suggest',
            '#nodes' => $nodes,
            '#term' => $term,
            '#type' => $type,
            '#cache' => [
                'keys' => [
                    'sg_search_term_suggestions_' . $term . "_". $type
                ],
                'tags' => [
                    'sg_search_term_suggestions_' . $term . "_". $type
                ],
                'contexts' => ['route']
            ],
        ];

$response = new Response($content);
return $response;
//retrun $build; //this does serve from CACHE
```

Looks like it never ends up hitting the cache mechanism. When I `return $build` then it does serve from cache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return a cacheable response. For example

```
use Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheableResponse;
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;

  /**
   * A route returning a CacheableResponse object.
   *
   * @return \Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheableResponseInterface
   *   A CacheableResponseInterface object.
   */
  public function cacheableResponse() {
    $user = User::load(1);
    $response = new CacheableResponse($user->label());
    $response->addCacheableDependency($user);
    return $response;
  }
```

From `Drupal\dynamic_page_cache_test\DynamicPageCacheTestController`.

There are multiple ways to add cache data to the response object additional to the one used in the example.

You can use addCacheTags()/addCacheContexts():

```
$response->getCacheableMetadata()->addCacheTags($tags);
$response->getCacheableMetadata()->addCacheContexts(['route']);
```

The route cache context is by the way not necessary in a controller because it depends already on the route.

Or add cacheable metadata contained in a render array

```
use Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheableMetadata;

$response->addCacheableDependency(CacheableMetadata::createFromRenderArray($build));
```

See also [How to handle cache metadata in a cacheable response?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/231642/how-to-handle-cache-metadata-in-a-cacheable-response) and [How to get cache metadata from nested render array when returning response?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/245715/how-to-get-cache-metadata-from-nested-render-array-when-returning-response)